# Exposing my go function output to Qml

Tags: go, qml

I have a function which give me a gdb backtrace in my go file something like:

```
func backtrace(){... fmt.Println ("backtrace details")}
```

I want expose this function output to qml. How can I do that?

EDIT:

```
func backtrace(){
    output,_:=debug.Send("stack-list-frames")
    pay:=output["payload"]

    payAssert:=pay.(map[string]interface{})

    stack:=payAssert["stack"]

    stackAssert:=stack.([]interface{})
    nbreFct:=len(stackAssert)
    for i:=0; i<=nbreFct-1 ; i++{
        stackSepare:=stackAssert[i]
        stackSepareAssert:=stackSepare.(map[string]interface{})

        frame:=stackSepareAssert["frame"]
        frameAssert:=frame.(map[string]interface{})

        index := strconv.Itoa(i)
        fmt.Println("Frame : ", index)

        //list variables by frame
        output_variables,_  := debug.Send("stack-list-variables","--thread","1","--frame",index,"--simple-values")
        map_variables := output_variables["payload"]
        m_variables := map_variables.(map[string]interface{})
        variables := m_variables["variables"]
        fmt.Println("Variables : ", variables)

        fun:=frameAssert["func"]
        line:=frameAssert["line"]
        level:=frameAssert["level"]

        fmt.Println("level : ",level,"function : ",fun ,"  line : ",line)
    }
}
```

How I can improve my code ouptut to expose the output to qml?

Comment: Do you know [this](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/qml.v0) way?